# Tails of power series based on its coefficients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Suppose we have to functions $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ that are polynomials of the same degree that is
\begin{align*}
g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k\\
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x^k
\end{align*}

then we have a following  statment:

> If $ |a_n| \ge |b_n|$ than  there exists $x_0$ such that  $|g(x)| \ge |f(x)|$
>   for all $x \ge x_0$.

**My questions:** Now suppose that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are power series, can we have a similar statement. For example, if 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|} \ge 1
\end{align}
then eventually $|g(x)| \ge |f(x)|$.

Comment: Let $g(x) = e^{-x},\, f(x) = e^x$. Then $\lvert a_n\rvert = \lvert b_n\rvert$ for all $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What if we impose that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ converge to zeros as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Maybe $ \lim \inf a_n - b_n \geq 0 $ would be a better condition to investigate.

Comment: $e^{-2x}$ and $e^{-x}$. Things are different with power series.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus  Yes, I am a looking for the condition that would show that tail of one power series dominates the other. Can you comment more on this?

Comment: @DanielFischer  Thanks. I was looking for some condition for coefficients that would say something about the tails. This was the one that came to my mind.

Comment: Actually, it has to be $\lim \inf a_n - b_n > 0$ strictly, if anything.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus  Can you please add it as an answer.

Comment: If the coefficients of both series are eventually non-negative, and we have $a_n \geqslant b_n$ for all $n \geqslant n_0$ with $a_n > b_n$ for at least one $n \geqslant n_0$ (and both series converge on all of $\mathbb{R}$), then we have $g(x) > f(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  what if coefficients are alternating? Is there any hope of deriving some condition?

Comment: Probably one can find conditions in such cases, but I don't think they'd be very useful.

Comment: @DanielFischer  I see. Thanks.

Comment: The starting statement is false. Consider $g(x) = x-1, f(x) =x.$

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim \inf a_n - b_n > 0$, that means there exists $N$ so $n>N \Rightarrow a_n > b_n$, then $f(x) > g(x)$ eventually for increasing $x$. Just find The suitable $x_0$ (if < 0 then use 0) for the truncation at $N$ and then note that all following terms of the $f$ expansion are greater than the corresponding ones in the $g$ expansion

Comment: There result assumes that $a_n$ are $b_n$ are positive, right?